# Include parentheses as part of a word while comparing using DeltaXML

Tags: xslt, deltaxml

We need to include parentheses as part of the word they surround while comparing.

For example:
Input A:
Hi (A)

Input B:
Hi (B)

Current Output:
Hi (`<Inserted>`B`<\Inserted>` `<Deleted>`A`<\Deleted>`)

Expected Output:
Hi `<Inserted>`(B)`<\Inserted>` `<Deleted>`(A)`<\Deleted>`

Thanks!

Comment: What is currently happening is that the input is split into 'word', 'punctuation' and 'space' elements. The output shows the 'word' A as deleted and 'B' as added. A solution would require you to use XSLT in an input filter to prevent '(A)' being split into separate elements for the comparison. I will post a sample of how XSLT can be used to do this with XML Compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I'm assuming you're using DeltaXML's DocumentComparator class.

The default behaviour for this class is to allow word-by-word comparison. It does this by splitting text up into space, punctuation or word elements.

So, for example, with Input A you would have:

```
...
<deltaxml:word>Hi</deltaxml:word>
<deltaxml:space>_</deltaxml:space>
<deltaxml:punctuation>(</deltaxml:punctuation>
<deltaxml:word>A</deltaxml:word>
<deltaxml:punctuation>)</deltaxml:punctuation>
...
```

As the 'A' input to the comparator.

To prevent text being split in this way you need an XSLT input filter that wraps specific text patterns in a deltaxml:word element with a deltaxml:word-by-word='false' attribute. Here is some sample XSLT that achieves this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:deltaxml="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="*|comment()|processing-instruction() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- 
    wrap a specific text pattern in text as a word-element
    in this case, any non-whitespace characters surrounded by '(' and ')' chars
  -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\([^\s]*?\))">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <deltaxml:word deltaxml:word-by-word="false">
          <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </deltaxml:word>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a tremendous help to me!